# Explanation of virtual table

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, vtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding the vtable entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712808/understanding-the-vtable-entries)

Using g++ version 4.6.3, 64-bit machine . I know compiler is free to implement virtual functions any way it wants. I want to know what happened here.

My class:

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
    public:
    virtual void func(){std::cout<<"in class test";}
};

int main()
{
    test obj;
    obj.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at virtual table generated by compiler,

```
Vtable for test
test::_ZTV4test: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0 (<---- what is this? )
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI4test)
16    (int (*)(...))test::func
```

At offset 8 it is RTTI

At offset 16 it is entry for virtual function.

My question is why is there entry for NULL at offset 0 or in other words what is the purpose of first entry?

P.S. I thought this could be related to alignment, but then I added more virtual functions but RTTI entry was still at offset 8.

Comment: I would guess it's reserved for the destructor (which you didn't add).

Comment: @John, added destructor still same  output. Also, is is necessary destructor will always be part of v-table?

Comment: It's very common to have a virtual destructor if you have any virtual functions. But it's not required. Oh well my guess was wrong.

Comment: @Anon - Did you make sure to mark the destructor as virtual?  John's explanation seems pretty reasonable, so I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: @XavierHolt , I did not initially but just tried as you and John suggested. RTTI is still at offset 8.

Comment: @Anon - Hmm.  Dunno, then - good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the first entry or the entry at 0 the is the offset to top pointer.

See [the following relevant stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712808/understanding-the-vtable-entries)

Looking through the remainder -fdump-class-hierarchy from your source code , most classes seem the have the first entry as `(int (*)(...))0` , the only  classes that don't have it as the first entry have it as the second and have the first entry as the offset to the parent class given the C++ STL class hierarchy for streams.

In the relevant question a dead link to some vtable examples is given, I believe a live version of that link is available [here](http://mentorembedded.github.com/cxx-abi/cxx-vtable-ex.html)

Another useful resource detailing the structure of vtables is [here](http://cppcoder.blogspot.jp/2008/04/virtual-table.html).

Comment: Yep. It's the "offset to top" pointer. Amongst other things, this is used to implement `dynamic_cast<void*>`. That cast gives a pointer to the most derived object. The standard of course doesn't say anything about vtables, or about how an implementation will go about making `dynamic_cast<void*>` function as required.